# Unable to access SD card on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, usb, sd-card

I can't access my SD card, not via the internal SD card reader of my laptop, nor via an external SD card reader.

I tried to use `dmesg` to find the cause of the issue, but when I attach the SD card to the internal reader nothing at all happens. Attaching it externally leads to:

```
[140886.727796] usb 4-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[140886.799854] usb 4-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[140886.975877] usb 4-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[140887.151952] usb 4-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[140887.223971] usb 4-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[140887.399956] usb 4-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[140887.576009] usb 4-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[140887.984099] usb 4-1.2: device not accepting address 11, error -32
[140888.056121] usb 4-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[140888.464233] usb 4-1.2: device not accepting address 12, error -32
[140888.464405] usb 4-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

How may I resolve this problem, preferably get the internal SD card reader to work, and access my SD card?

**edit:** the listed daemon messages are related solely to the external card reader. I've just tried the card reader on a second system and the same errors are printed. It seems like either the device doesn't work with linux or is broken after all.

The internal card reader still doesn't work and shows no reaction, based on `dmesg`

**edit2:** the internal SD card reader works fine on windows.

Comment: was it working before? I have killed already one of my MicroSD cards abusing it with Linux tests.

Comment: The SD card works fine on my other systems, the external card reader as well. I can't recall whether I used the card reader on this system before or not.

Comment: Are you using an USB hub?

Comment: No, this occurs on all USB ports of the notebook, without hub. The external reader works fine as well on other systems and the USB ports all work with other devices.

Comment: what is the output of "lsusb"?

Comment: that's odd.. I re-attached the external card reader to answer your question and now it seems to work. Quite random I'd say.

Comment: In the same USB port?

Comment: oh man.. I was happy too early. Yes the same USB port as before. But seconds after it was available, the same erros were printed, using dmesg and the SD card was not available anymore. Here's the log http://paste.debian.net/hidden/206798e2/

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-redhat-centos-kernel-usb-reset-high-speed-ehci_hcd/

Comment: I've updated the OP. It seems like the external card reader somehow broke since I last used it. The internal card reader doesn't react to anything. I'll try the hardware on windows later.

Comment: I suspected from the beginning either power issues or flaky hardware. Wish you luck

Comment: Have you checked if there is any BIOS updates available? Do you have other USB devices attached? Have you tried removing all? Have you tried  warm / cold boot? Is there any messages on boot about the internal USB reader?

Comment: I'm on the latest BIOS. I've detached all other USB devices and retried. Cold/Warm boot not tried, will do that.

Comment: Works with windows and I can't seem to find any messages after cold/warm boots.

Comment: Does this work? `modprobe -rv ehci-hcd && modprobe -av ehci-hcd` ? (I'm only throwing around wild suggestions.)

Comment: `modprobe: FATAL: Module ehci_hcd is in use.`